# interpreting error response for BCP in operators

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to interpret my BCP IN error response.
The actual data has privacy data so I can not show it, but I'll ask around it.

if the response is: `#@ Row 257054, Column 150: String data, right truncation @#`

`Column 150`, do I assume that column counts starts at `Column 1` or `Column 0`?

and my second half of the question.
What happens if the value to be inserted is NULL, which is going into a NULLABLE field.  How do I translate this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the column numbers, you can test it easily by doing it with a file that has a value in the first column that is longer than size of the char -ish data type you have in the destination table.

Considering NULLs there's a switch for bcp to keep nulls, which is: **-k**